# Data Base Structure

Tags: database-design

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 = Visit (Someone came into the store)
Table 2 = VisitReason (Why they came into the store).

Is there any reason why table 2 could be all boolean fields that get translated into checkboxes in my mvc view?

This would be an alternative to creating a record for every reason for their visit that is associated with the visit.

Thoughts?
(Yes I'm new and learning).

Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Think six months in the future.  What if you need to add a new reason?  Do you add another column?  What if the table has 800 million rows by that time?  It's going to take a long time to restructure the table to add that column.  Whereas if you add one row per reason, you can add a new reason type at any time.
2. Imagine the query to answer the question, "show me users who had at least two reasons to come into the store."  That is, any two columns are true.  Then extend that to three reasons.
3. What indexes would you create on this table of *N* columns to speed up searching for a given reason.  One index on each column?  What if I want to know about visitors who had two reasons?  Now you need one index for each combination of any two reasons.
4. Is it valid for all the boolean fields to be false?  That is, the customer visited but for none of the reasons.  If that's invalid, how would you ensure that at least one is checked as true?

Comment: Additionally, by making everything a boolean field, one is making each row larger than it could be (and thus wasting space), since most users would not pick every single reason. One is using space for each possible `(user, reason)` pair, when you could just use enough for each actually selected reason.

Comment: Rules of normalization aren't academic or arbitrary -- there are practical consequences to breaking the rules.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer having table2 be one record per reason.  The list of reasons might be growing, and should in my opinion be maintained in a separate lookup table (table 3) instead of as part of the table definition.  As the list grows, there might be some waste of space if only a small percentage of the possible reasons apply to any given visit.